# THREE Js: How to make objects follow objects?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I am trying to make the PONG Game and for the part to play against the computer, I tried to make that the computer should follow the y-axes of the ball. Both the ball and the computer have a different movement speed (vy), so they should not make a parallel line. So far the ball is moving correctly but the computer won't move at all. The code below is in the requestAnimationFrame().

PONG --> https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Pong.png

```
delta_t = 0.02;
t = t + delta_t;

// Computer should go up
if (computer.position.y < ball.position.y ) {
y_computer = computer.position.y;
vy_computer = vy_computer;
t = 0;
}

// Computer should go down
 if (computer.position.y > ball.position.y  ) {
 y_computer = computer.position.y;
 vy_computer = -vy_computer;
 t = 0; 
 }
 computer.position.set(-370, y_computer + vy_computer * t , 40);
```

This is the site that I'm using --> http://gamingjs.com/ice/

Comment: any error messages in browser console?

Comment: No, seems alright for the console.

Comment: did I get it right, that no matter, if `computer.position.y` is more or less than `ball.position.y`, then `t` is always `0`, thus `y_computer + vy_computer * t` is always equals to `y_computer` because `vy_comptuer * t` = `vy_computer * 0`?

Comment: Oh sry, I didn't include the code t = t + 0.02   in this question. But t = 0  should be the start when the computer starts to move up or down. I did it the same with the ball so I thought that I could do it with the movement of the computer too.

Answer (score 0):

As I get it. You have to check, if directions of the ball and the "computer" are the same, and if not, then check if position of the "computer" is in range of position of the ball plus "epsilon" and position of the ball minus "epsilon", and if it's in the range then negate the direction of the "computer"

```
  if (Math.sign(direction_follower.z) != Math.sign(direction.z)){
    if (follower.position.z <= origin.position.z + epsilon &&
        follower.position.z >= origin.position.z - epsilon)
        direction_follower.negate();
  }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/j0dbngy3/) example.